# Upgrade org-mode with Aquamacs

Tags: emacs, aquamacs, org-mode

As is asked and answered in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622603/org-mode-setup-problem-when-trying-to-use-capture), Aquamacs has the org-mode that is pretty old, and there are some problems with capturing.

How can I upgrade the org-mode with Aquamacs? Is it OK just copy lisp/*.el to somewhere?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can put the .el files pretty much where you want to, but you'll need to add the directory to your emacs load-path with something like:

```
(setq load-path (cons "~/path/to/orgdir/lisp" load-path))
```

Stick that in your `.emacs` file.

There's more info on the [org-mode installation page](http://orgmode.org/manual/Installation.html).

Comment: I did, but M-x org-version gives me 6.33X, I guess it still uses the old version in Aquamacs.

Comment: I got something wrong, it works fine. Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem, prosseek, it would be nice to know what it is that you did wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Let me summarize the steps I carried out eventually, to use the package manager. Note, I am using emacs 23
based editor which was shipped with org-mode 6.33.

### Install the package manager

- Download the `packages.el` file from [here](http://repo.or.cz/w/emacs.git/blob_plain/1a0a666f941c99882093d7bd08ced15033bc3f0c:/lisp/emacs-lisp/package.el). Save in in `~/Library/elisp` for example.
- Add the following code to the `.emacs`:

  (setq load-path (cons "~/Library/elisp" load-path))
  (require 'package)
  (package-initialize)

### Verify

To verify this part, in `emacs` hit `M-x list-packages RET org`. Here
you should see a list of optional packages. *Note:* you may ignore the
warning: `failed to download org-mode archive`.

### Updating org-mode

- Enter the `list-packages` Hit `M-x list-packages RET`.
- In there mark for installation by `i` the org package and the `x` for
  the actual installation.

  ### Restart emacs

### Verify

Hit `M-x locate-library RET org` to verify the installation. You should now
have org-mode up and running.

Comment: Aquamacs 3.0 (in alpha) is based on Emacs 24 so the package manager is built in./ So you can start with the Updating org-mode section.

Answer (score 0):

I found this slightly more helpful snippet from the EmacsWiki (http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CustomizeAquamacs):

> **Upgrading org-mode or other major-modes in Aquamacs**

```
    # Name of your emacs binary
    EMACS=/Applications/Aquamacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Aquamacs

    # Where local lisp files go.
    lispdir   = /Applications/Aquamacs.app/Contents/Resources/lisp 

    # Where info files go.
    infodir = /Applications/Aquamacs.app/Contents/Resources/info
```

> --D.H. Ardell

*Update (March 2013):* Make the assignments above in `local.mk` after having first cloned it from `mk/default.mk`
Be sure to save the updated clone (`local.mk`) into the top-level directory (i.e. above mk itself) to avoid compilation errors.

Comment: and where do the styles from the etc directory go for the OpenDocument Text Export?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out—just put the entire etc directory next to the lisp directory. so in the following example, it would be in the orgdir (setq load-path (cons "~/path/to/orgdir/lisp" load-path)) (taken from Doug Harris' answer)